# Convert hash into number

Tags: python, pandas

I want to convert the names of a dataset into numbers. I have a dataset made with pandas that looks like this:

[image]

I want the `user_id` and `business_id` to be numbers. So that I can easily go to `user 1` and `business 1`.

I don't know how to do this while still keeping the IDs identical. So I don't want the same business to have two different numbers. Does anyone know how I can do this easily? I know how to convert the IDs to numbers but I don't know how can I make sure that the same id keeps the same number.

Comment: (1) Show a reasonable part of the dataset as properly formatted text in the question, not as image or external link. (2) Pandas provides a lot of conversion functions e. g. from string to number. (3) Show what you tried as properly formatted code in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try the use of `dict`, because a `dict` stores distinct keys only. For example:

```
df1=pd.DataFrame({'business_id':['fszudif-6','fszudif-6','fsfhdks'],
             'user_id':['sdf','sdf','ui5'],
             'col3':[100,200,300]})
dict1=dict(zip(df1['business_id'],df1['business_id'].apply(lambda 
    x:hash(x))))
print (dict1)
df1['business_id']=df1['business_id'].apply(lambda x: dict1[x])
print (df1)
```

gives you a dictionary with only two keys, because the value 'fszudif-6' from column `business_id` is repeated.

```
{3071153201467878330: 'fszudif-6', 4676342635135106290: 'fsfhdks'}
           business_id user_id  col3
0  3071153201467878330     sdf   100
1  3071153201467878330     sdf   200
2  4676342635135106290     ui5   300
```

In the `lambda` function you can change `hash(x)` to any function you prefer to convert `str` to `int`, it is just an example.

Comment: If it works, could you either upvote it or accept it as an answer?